# CheckBox Grouping

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have 4 checkboxes on a winform

I need to group them in such a way that

-> User should be able to check more than one checkboxes

-> User should not be allowed to  uncheck all the checkboxes,

that is at any point of time atleast one checkbox should be checked,

(I  need  to  somehow  prevent  user  from unchecking last checkboxe)

How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know if "grouping" is the word you're looking for. Thought this was about design/appearance. And I don't think it's good UI to *prevent* the user from unchecking the last box. What if they wanted to uncheck it and had every intention of checking a new one afterwords? Why not validate when they hit "submit" or "ok"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CheckedChanged event to check the state of the check boxes.  Don't allow them to uncheck if there will be none checked.

Also you can have the checkbox controls pointed to the same event using something like below.

`chkboxes1.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkboxes_CheckedChanged);
chkboxes2.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkboxes_CheckedChanged);
chkboxes3.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkboxes_CheckedChanged);`